# Изучаю Python и застрял на kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю  Python и застрял:

```
def tracklist(*artist,**tracks):
    for name in artist:
        print(name)
    for key, value in tracks.items():
        print(f"'ALBUM':{key}, 'TRACK':{value}")


tracklist(Woodkid={"The Golden Age": "Run Boy Run",
               "On the Other Side": "Samara"},
      Cure={"Disintegration": "Lovesong",
            "Wish": "Friday I'm in love"})
```

Функция должна распечатать значения из словаря в следующем виде:

```
Woodkid
ALBUM: The Golden Age TRACK: Run Boy Run
ALBUM: On the Other Side TRACK: Samara
Cure
ALBUM: Disintegration TRACK: Lovesong
ALBUM: Wish TRACK: Friday I'm in love
```

Где-то закралась ошибка, не могу найти

Comment: А что сейчас выводит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**tracks` (`kwargs`) это словарь из именованных параметров функции, у вас это будет `Woodkid` и `Cure`, а в `*artist` попадут позиционные параметры, у вас их нет, т.к. только именованные передаете, поэтому в `artist` (`args`) будет пусто

С учетом выше написанного код поменял на:

```
def tracklist(**tracks):
    for name, tracks in tracks.items():
        print(name)
        for album, track in tracks.items():
            print(f"ALBUM: {album}, TRACK: {track}")


tracklist(
    Woodkid={"The Golden Age": "Run Boy Run", "On the Other Side": "Samara"},
    Cure={"Disintegration": "Lovesong", "Wish": "Friday I'm in love"}
)
```

Результат:

```
Woodkid
ALBUM: The Golden Age, TRACK: Run Boy Run
ALBUM: On the Other Side, TRACK: Samara
Cure
ALBUM: Disintegration, TRACK: Lovesong
ALBUM: Wish, TRACK: Friday I'm in love
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!!!

Comment: @ProTrader, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [принять мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)